# Fancybox behaves like link, not modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I'm new here. I am studying computer science in college right now, and need some help to figure out something in a project i'm doing for a student organization.
So I am writing a website, and it's my first time, and I cannot get fancybox to work at all (there is a picture I want to behave in a "click to enlarge"-type way). Here's my html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="experience-us">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Experience us</h2>
      <p>See what it's like to be a part of the ********** team</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>
            <a class="thumbnail fancybox" href="images/small.jpg" title="Example title"><img src="images/small.jpg"></a>
          </p>
          .
          .
          .
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have jquery loaded twice, get rid of the bottom one!

Comment: Remove the las jQuery line from the bottom of your page